# Cambiar extensión de imágenes en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código el cual guarda imágenes en el servidor, el problema es que las debo convertir todas a .jpg, pero no lo hace bien porque al abrir la imagen muestre el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public ActionResult PatchT(int id, [FromForm] IFormFile imagen)
{
  try
  {
    var model= _context.MyModel.Find(id);
    if (model.Id == id)
    {
      if (imagen != null)
      {
      var extension = Path.GetExtension(imagen.FileName).Substring(1);                       
      var imagePath = "//192.168.0.1/" + id + "."+extension;                        

      using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(imagePath))
      {                           
        imagePath = Path.ChangeExtension(imagePath, ".jpg");

        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(imagePath);
        f.MoveTo(Path.ChangeExtension(imagePath, ".jpg"));
        imagen.CopyToAsync(stream);
      }
      model.ImageAutoriza = imagePath;
    }
  _context.SaveChanges();
 return Ok(model);
 }
 else
 {
  return BadRequest();
 }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  return BadRequest(e.Message);
}
}
```

Comment: No puedes cambiar el formato/codificación de la imagen con simplemente el cambio de extensión. Deberías buscar una librería (o código) que te ayude a "convertir" la imagen de un formato a otro.

Comment: Hay bastantes cosas para revisar, https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=C%23+change+png+to+jpg aquí un punto de partida. Espero lo tomes a bien, va en buena onda :)